# Visual Basic has insufficient disk space

Tags: windows-xp, visual-basic

I'm trying to download visual basic 2010 Express But every time I click on install button this shows up to me:

[image]

When I try to select a different destination folder, I get the same error.

[image]

When I click on *Ignore*, it starts to download. Then it tells me to Exit.

Comment: Hi Mohamed. In the future please don't write your posts **all in bold**, and use our internal image uploader to add screenshots to your post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you select a different drive, visual studio will install some components in your root drive. In your case the C:\ drive. It forces you to install in the root drive because some components like .net framework and stuff like that work directly with your operating system so is usually installed in your C:\windows\system32.

**In a nut shell, there is no way to avoid that 2.2gb space it needs for visual studio to work correctly**

Comment: You mean the error message says exactly what's wrong ???

Comment: So there's no way to fix this problem

Comment: @MohamedFathy as far as I know, there is no way to fix this problem.